# PDF File upload in custom mudule in admin in 2.0

Tags: magento-2.0.7

How we can upload the PDF file in magento 2,0 from admin module ?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please provide more context, otherwise it's hard to help you. Where should this upload form be integrated? What do you already have? For which part do you need help: Creating a form, processing the post request, both?